# how to solve this double integral with polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Can i use the polar coordinates to solve this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x}^{\sqrt{8-x^2}} \frac{1}{5+x^2+y^2}dydx$$

Comment: Sketch the domain of integration.

Comment: It seems homework. What course is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar coordinates would be a good choice. Here's the drawing of region we are integrating over,

[image]

It is circular-ish. Note that $\sqrt{8-x^2}=y$ means that $8-x^2=y^2$. Or $x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{8})^2$. So $r=\sqrt{8}$ and $y \geq 0$.

As for $y=x$, in polar coordinates that translates to $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})=\arctan (1)=\frac{\pi}{4}=\theta$. So in polar coordinates we have,

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{8}} \frac{r}{5+r^2} dr d\theta$$

Comment: Semi-off topic: which app are you using??

Comment: I'm using Desmos @Stefano

Comment: thank you, i was doing that but the limits i used were wrong. And the app he used was desmos.